# Animation in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to add some animation to my custom button which I created via Canvas in Tkinter. However, I can't properly manage events, and my animation often just does not work as it should.

Here is a code:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)


class AACloseButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, _x=170, _y=0, fg="black", **kw):
        super().__init__(borderwidth=0, height=10, width=10, bg='white', **kw)
        self.cnv = Canvas(self, highlightthickness=0, relief="flat", height=32, width=201, bg="white")
        self.cnv.pack(side=RIGHT)
        d1, d2 = 100, 31
        self.check1, self.check2 = False, False
        # self.left = False
        self.cover = self.cnv.create_rectangle(_x, _y, _x + d1, _y + d2, tags=["p098", "io9"])
        self.text = self.cnv.create_text(_x + (d1 / 2) + 15, _y + (d2 / 2), fill=fg,
                                         text="Close", tags=["p097", "io9"])
        self.rect3 = self.cnv.create_rectangle(_x + 1, _y + 1, _x + d2, _y + d2, tags=["p092", "io9"], fill="red",
                                               width=0)
        self.l1 = self.cnv.create_line(_x + 2, _y + 2, _x + d2 - 2, _y + d2 - 2, fill="white", tags=["io9", "p094"])
        self.l2 = self.cnv.create_line(_x + d2 - 2, _y + 2, _x + 2, _y + d2 - 2, fill="white", tags=["io9", "p093"])

        self.cnv.bind("<Leave>", self._aout)
        self.cnv.bind("<Enter>", self._ain)

    def _ain(self, event):
        print("Inserted")
        try:
            del self.r2
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        def worker():
            try:
                xchg = self.r3.is_alive()
            except AttributeError:
                xchg = False
            self.check1 = True
            if not xchg:
                for i in range(30):
                    self.cnv.move("io9", -2, 0)
                    time.sleep(0.0001)
                    if self.check2:
                        self.check2 = False
                        self.check1 = False

                        self.cnv.move("io9", (i + 1) * 2, 0)
                        break
                self.check1 = False

        self.r2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True)
        self.r2.start()

    def _aout(self, event):
        print("Left")
        try:
            del self.r3
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        def worker():
            self.check2 = True
            if not self.r2.is_alive():
                for i in range(30):
                    self.cnv.move("io9", 2, 0)
                    time.sleep(0.0001)
                    if self.check1:
                        self.check1 = False
                        self.check2 = False

                        self.cnv.move("io9", -(i + 1) * 2, 0)
                        break
                self.check2 = False

        self.r3 = threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True)
        self.r3.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2)
    q = AACloseButton()
    q.pack(pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Here is code with `.after()`, instead of threads:**

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)


class AACloseButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, _x=170, _y=0, fg="black", **kw):
        super().__init__(borderwidth=0, height=10, width=10, bg='white', **kw)
        self.cnv = Canvas(self, highlightthickness=0, relief="flat", height=32, width=201, bg="white")
        self.cnv.pack(side=RIGHT)
        d1, d2 = 100, 31
        self.co1, self.co2 = 0, 0
        self.check1, self.check2 = False, False
        # self.left = False
        self.cover = self.cnv.create_rectangle(_x, _y, _x + d1, _y + d2, tags=["p098", "io9"])
        self.text = self.cnv.create_text(_x + (d1 / 2) + 15, _y + (d2 / 2), fill=fg,
                                         text="Close", tags=["p097", "io9"])
        self.rect3 = self.cnv.create_rectangle(_x + 1, _y + 1, _x + d2, _y + d2, tags=["p092", "io9"], fill="red",
                                               width=0)
        self.l1 = self.cnv.create_line(_x + 2, _y + 2, _x + d2 - 2, _y + d2 - 2, fill="white", tags=["io9", "p094"],
                                       width=2)
        self.l2 = self.cnv.create_line(_x + d2 - 2, _y + 2, _x + 2, _y + d2 - 2, fill="white", tags=["io9", "p093"],
                                       width=2)

        self.cnv.bind("<Leave>", self._aout)
        self.cnv.bind("<Enter>", self._ain)

    def _ain(self, event=None):
        self.co1 += 1
        self.check2 = True
        self.cnv.move("io9", -2, 0)
        if self.check1:
            self.check1 = False
            self.cnv.move("io9", (self.co1 + 1) * 2, 0)
            self.co1 = 0
        elif self.co1 == 29:
            self.check1 = False
            self.check2 = False
            self.co1 = 0
        else:
            self.after(10, self._ain)

    def _aout(self, event=None):
        self.co2 += 1
        self.check1 = True
        self.cnv.move("io9", 2, 0)
        if self.check2:
            self.check2 = False
            self.cnv.move("io9", -(self.co2 + 1) * 2, 0)
            self.co2 = 0
        elif self.co2 == 29:
            self.check1 = False
            self.check2 = False
            self.co2 = 0
        else:
            self.after(10, self._aout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2)
    q = AACloseButton()
    q.pack(pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```

For now, the button is workable, but with some bugs: When you try to leave `canvas` with the pressed button on a mouse "Leave" event triggers two times (once pointer leaves a canvas and once on the release of a button). And, in addition, sometimes, when you move your mouse very quickly, the button can mistake its position.

Could you, please, explain to me what I did wrong?

**I have remade my program with `.after()`, as @TheLizzard suggested. It works a lot better; *however, a bug with a pressed button is not fixed.***

Comment: Using threads when using `tkinter` can be a bad idea. Please look at `.after` scripts.

Comment: You definitely don't need threads for such a simple animation.

Comment: There are many questions and answers here on this topic — please spend a little time searching for and reading them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using TkVideo. It plays videos using the Tkinter Label widget.

It is another library and can be installed using `pip install tkVideo`.

The example from https://pypi.org/project/tkVideo/:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo

root = Tk()
my_label = Label(root)
my_label.pack()
player = tkvideo.tkvideo("C:\\path\\to\\video.mp4", my_label, loop = 1, size = (1280,720))
player.play()

root.mainloop()
```

You can make a video and play it using TkVideo.

For more information, please visit https://pypi.org/project/tkVideo/.